# Create snapshots of certain folders from remote master

Tags: git-clone, git-lfs

I want to create a copy of certain folders (`FOLDER1/SUBFOLDER1`, `FOLDER2`) from a remote `master` branch. I'm not interested in any historical data, other branches, I don't want to modify, or push back this data later. This is my current approach which has been working so far, but lately is failing with a git lfs "[404] Object does not exist on the server"

```
mkdir -p $(LOCAL_FOLDER)
cd $(LOCAL_FOLDER) 
git init
git config core.sparseCheckout true
git remote add origin git@$(REMOTE_REPO):$(GITFILE).git
echo "FOLDER1/SUBFOLDER1\nFOLDER2" > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git fetch --depth 1 origin master
git checkout -f master
```

Standard git/linux commands should be preferred.

Comment: Git literally can't produce a Git-LFS error; only Git-LFS can produce such an error. I've updated your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would try at least a [`git lfs fetch --all`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-fetch.1.ronn) after your shallow fetch, in order to make sure you have all the LFS objects resolved.

If the error persists, try a [full LFS clone](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#pulling-and-cloning=), take what you need from the result, and delete the clone.